# VBA How to Update fetched Data to Data origin row?

Tags: excel, vba

**Table of Contents:**

1. Situation (already working code that is used)
2. Question
3. Example

I'm currently working on a project that is supposed to make life easier at work (I'm very much a beginner).

Note: I'm not using UserForms

**1. Situation:**

I've already got some help programming a Macro that lets me copy Values I put into the Range `E2:E9` to a range starting with `C13:J13` and then continuing to the next empty row downward while preventing Duplicates. So to put it simple it says = **"If value E2 already exists in column C then MsgBox "Value already exists!" and exit sub else transpond data to the next empty row in range C:J**.

The code for that looks like this.

```
Sub NeuesKFZ()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, lastErow As Long, matchCel As Range
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 arr = sh.Range("E2:E9").Value
 lastErow = sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
 If Range("E2") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Wählen Sie ein KFZ aus!"
        Range("E2").Select
    Exit Sub
End If
 
If lastErow < 13 Then lastErow = 13
 'check if the range has not been alredy copied:
 Set matchCel = sh.Range("C13:C" & lastErow - 1).Find(WHAT:=sh.Range("E2").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
 If Not matchCel Is Nothing Then MsgBox sh.Range("E2").Value & " Existiert bereits in Zelle  " & matchCel.Address & "!": Exit Sub
 sh.Range("C" & lastErow).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
 sh.Range("E2:E9").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Now there's also a Makro in which I can pull up already stored data with `E2` acting as the search criteria. In simple terms.

If `E2` exist in `C` get Values of that row and copy/transpond them to `E3:E9` (`E2` not necessary because correct value already present).

The code looks something like this

```
Sub KFZAufrufen()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, arr, lastErow As Long, matchCel As Range  'Nötige Variablen
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet                                           'Variabel Deklaration
 arr = sh.Range("E2:E9").Value                                  'Wenn in Zukunft mehr Daten aufgenommen werden sollen hier E10 verändern
 lastErow = sh.Range("C" & sh.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 
 
 If Range("E2") = "" Then
        MsgBox "Wählen Sie ein KFZ aus!"                        'Zwingt den Nutzer ein KFZ aus der Dropdown in E2 zu wählen, sollte nicht verändert werden
        Range("E2").Select
    Exit Sub
End If
 
 
 If lastErow < 13 Then lastErow = 13
                                                                'Suche nach dem KFZ welches durch die Zelle E2 definiert wird
 Set matchCel = sh.Range("C13:C" & lastErow - 1).Find(WHAT:=sh.Range("E2").Value, LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
 If Not matchCel Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox sh.Range("E2").Value & " wurde gefunden in " & matchCel.Address & "."
                                                                'Fahrzeugdaten aus der Tabelle in die in die Bearbeitung hoch holen
    sh.Range("E3:E9").Value = Application.Transpose(sh.Range(matchCel.Offset(0, 1), matchCel.Offset(0, 7)).Value)
    Exit Sub
End If
 sh.Range("C" & lastErow).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
 sh.Range("E2:E9").ClearContents
End Sub
```

**2. QUESTION:**

How can I Update the retrieved Data in `E3:E9` to that exact row I got the values from in the first place?

**3. Example:**

User puts in value `y` into `E2`.

Value `y` is found in `C30`.

`Range` `D30:J30` is transponded to `Range` `E3:E9` (Again `C30` is not needed because Value `y` is already present in `E2`).

User changes Value `x` in `E3` to value `z`.

Value `x` is replaced with value `z` in `D30`.

I really don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get some input back from the user to indicate that they do want to update the existing values.  I'd do it by replacing this line of code in your first sub above

```
If Not matchCel Is Nothing Then MsgBox sh.Range("E2").Value & " Existiert bereits in Zelle  " & matchCel.Address & "!": Exit Sub
```

with something like this

```
If Not matchCel Is Nothing Then
    If MsgBox(sh.Range("E2").Value & " Existiert bereits in Zelle  " & matchCel.Address & "!" & vbCrLf & "Update Existing Values?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
         sh.Range("C" & matchCel.Row).Resize(1, UBound(arr)).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
    End If
    Exit Sub
End If
```

See if that works for you

Comment: I'm on it. Please give me a minute to test it out!

Comment: Yes it worked thank you VERY much! This is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: Do I have the right thinking that I also could exchange `Application.Transposed` with `.ClearContents` or am I wrong? Just saying If I want to execute a different makro that deletes those contents.

Comment: @Panderz_GG I don't think you'd use `.ClearContents` with `Application` (I could be wrong) but you can definitely use it with a `Range`  This link has more info on it  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.clearcontents

Comment: Thank you for the link I'll have a look into it and thanks again you made my life so much easier with 6 lines of code. Have a nice day and stay safe!